# Singularity of hypersurface section along points in a plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a very general sextic surface and $H$ be a hyper plane in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Then it is know that $X \cap H$ can have at most $3$ singularity.  Suppose $Y$ be another irreducible hypersurface. Now my question is can $X \cap Y$ be singular at more than 3 points of $H \cap X$ ?

Comment: Surely yes if Y has high enough degree - just pick $100$ points of $H \cap X$ and choose $Y$ vanishing to degree $1000$ on all of them, or whatever you feel like.

Comment: why these points will be singular for the intersection ?

Comment: If the points lie on a line then it is easy to find. But is it possible if the points on $H$ are in linearly general position ?

Comment: These will be singular because the Jacobian matrix doesn't have full rank (because one of the rows vanishes). This construction certainly works for linearly general position points.